# C while loop to calculate interest

Tags: crash, c

I want my program to use a while loop and perform this interest calculation.  I would like the loop to end if -1 is entered as the value of principal.

I feel like I'm missing something very vital and that it's not allowing my program to run accordingly.

The program will also sometimes crash and other times run, but never calculate the interest.

```
float interest;
float rate;
float principal;
int days;


while(principal !=-1)
{
        interest = principal * rate * days / 365;


    printf("%s""Enter loan principal (-1 to end):");
    scanf("%f", &principal);

    printf("%s""Enter interest rate:");
    scanf("%f", &rate);

    printf("%s""Enter term of the loan in days:");
    scanf("%d", &days);

    printf("The interest charge is $%.2f", interest);
}
```

Comment: The `interest = ...` line should be after the user has input and before printing the result. But it looks like it should print something the second time through. What error does it give when it crashes?

Comment: 1) the returned value from scanf (and family) should always be tested to assure the operation was successful  2) the last call to printf() first parameter (the format string) should be ended with '\n' or the call to printf() followed by a call: fflush(stdout);  so the output occurs at the proper times.

Comment: the variable 'principal' is being tested at the beginning of the while loop  before it is set to an known value.  suggest float principal = 0,0f;   the '-1' in the while loop is not a valid check against a float value.  suggest while( principal >= 0.0f)

Comment: `principal`, `rate` and `days` are used uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

You have several classic programming mistakes here.  This question should be migrated to StackOverflow, but I'll provide an answer here before then.

When contemplating behaviour of a given block of code, always think about "what is the value."

In this case, at line 3

```
 float principal
```

what is the value stored in the variable principal after this executes?  [simple answer:  we don't know.  we would need to know what type of compiler, which version and what flags were used to created the executable from this source]

Why don't we know?  compare with,

```
float principal = 0.0
```

now we can say clearly what the value is.

So, given we don't know what the initial value of principal is, what will happen when it is compared to a value of -1?  For this we need to understand the internals of how floating point values and integers are stored on your particular hardware platform.  Let's pick a common format of -1 which (if we represent the bits in Hexadecimal) corresponds to 0xFFFF.  Now we are going to compare that value with value of principal ... which it will most certainly not be equal to since principal currently has random/unknown data ... this is good news as we will enter the loop!  sometimes ... when principal happens to have the bit pattern of 0xFFFF

So, then why does the program crash, when it does enter the loop?
That has to do with a syntax error in your code, which I think produced a warning message when it was compiled ...

I'll only look at one line, but all the printf statements have the same problem.

```
printf("%s""Enter loan principal (-1 to end):");
```

printf expects, at basic, one argument to print OR  two arguments - the first being the format of how to print the second.

In this case, you have only one string -- the compiler has mashed the two quoted items into a single argument to printf ... which is looking at the format specifier of %s and expecting a second string ... so it takes a random value from the stack and uses it to print a second string.  you should have:

```
printf("%s", "Enter loan principal (-1 to end):");
```

Fix up these errors and your code will run properly.  If you give good values for principal and other variables, then it will run correctly.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the program does run and loop correctly but when I do enter -1 condition it continues to run until completion once more. How would I end the program as soon as principal = -1?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "as soon as" ... the loop will currently exit once principal has a value of -1.  If you mean "and dont' do any other additional steps of the loop" ... well, then, you need to put the "is value -1" check immediately after reading the new value ... re-arrange the loop body appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

#### In C and C++, a variable generally doesn't have any specific value until you assign it one

- A key part of C and C++ programming is that most variables you declare are not assigned a value unless you explicitly give it a value. If you don't specify a value for the variable, the initial value present in the variable is said to be *undefined*, which means it can literally be anything.
- On most systems, this will likely just be whatever value that happens to be in the memory location reserved for that variable, which is effectively random.
- As a result, you cannot assume the variables you declared have some known value such as 0 unless you assign them one. In your case, you'll need to initialize the variables when you declare them:

  ```
  float interest = 0.0f;
  float rate = 0.0f;
  float principal = 0.0f;
  int days = 0;
  ```

  Only then can you rely on a valid value being stored in each variable.

#### If you want to exit mid-loop, you should check the exit condition at the appropriate time

- If you want the program to exit the loop as soon as the user enters -1 for the principal, you'll need to change the loop to check just after the user enters the value.
- This means you'll need to change the condition in `while` to `true` (so that it won't exit at the start or end of a loop iteration) and add a conditional `break` within the loop. You don't *have* to check at the start or end of the loop.

#### Miscellaneous code mistakes

- You also shouldn't compute the interest value until after you get them from the user. This means the computation should be placed after the input prompts, but before you output the result.
- If your `printf()` statements print only a static string, you don't need to specify anything other than the string to print. There also should be a space at the end of the prompt, so that the input isn't right next to the prompt with no space.

Code with the corrections made follows:

```
/* Declare and initialize all variables. */
float interest = 0.0f;
float rate = 0.0f;
float principal = 0.0f;
int days = 0;    

/* Don't check for any condition at the start of the loop, just run the loop. */
while(true)
{
    printf("Enter loan principal (-1 to end): ");
    scanf("%f", &principal);

    /* If principal is -1, exit from the loop now. */
    if(principal == -1.0f)
        break;

    printf("Enter interest rate: ");
    scanf("%f", &rate);

    printf("Enter term of the loan in days: ");
    scanf("%d", &days);

    /* Compute the interest charge once the input is read. */
    interest = principal * rate * days / 365;

    /* Display the result. */
    printf("The interest charge is $%.2f", interest);
}
```